# Check if variable is empty not working | NodeJS, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build a blog API, and right now I have three fields in my schema:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Title is required"]
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Content is required"]
  }
})
```

I also have `createPost` function, that is supposed to create a post (no shit):

```
// Create post
const createPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title
  const content = req.body.content

  console.log('body', req.body) // getting output

  if (!title) {
    res.status(422).json({ error: "Titel saknas!!!" })
  }

  if (!content) {
    res.status(422).json({ error: "Skriv något för fan!" })
  }

  const post = new Post({
    title,
    content
  })

  post.save((err, post) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ err })
    }
      res.status(201).json({ post })
  })
}
```

I have those two if statements to check if the title or the content is empty, but that is not working. I tried to send a POST request with Postman:
[image]

But the error says that my `title` is missing. But I am passing in my title key. 
[image]

So I wonder why this is not working, it feels like some obvious stuff, but I just can't get this to work.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: it seems to me that req.body is just a string and referring req.body.title gets you then undefined which causes the jump into the if block

Comment: Make sure you have installed and enabled the `body-parser` middleware (or one with similar functionality). EDIT: And set Postman to use `application/json` for the Content-Type header :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Postman too well, but I'm going to guess that setting the body content type to `raw` uploads the body as `text/plain`, which means `body-parser` will not parse it in any way (`console.log('body', typeof req.body)` will show *"body string"*).

Instead, try setting the content type to `application/json` (and make sure that your server uses the JSON middleware from `body-parser`).

Comment: You're right! This was a silly mistake! 

I changed it to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and now I'm seeing my error message! Thanks!